# Query SQL Server with wildcard IN the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I need to build a query where the criteria must match with wildcard in the database.

With an example it will be clearest.

I have a column with a field like this `963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX`.
The `~` char is a wildcard.
So the following criterias must match :

- `~63-4-AKS~M`
- `963-4-AKS1M`
- `963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150AAA`
- `963-4-AKSAM2RN21AXA150AAA`
- `963-4-AKSCM2RN21AXA150A060C1D1DSDXX`
- `963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX`

I've tried so much things my head hurt :(

In the other way (with wildcard from the criteria) no problem, easy. But in this way I cannot find the key.

The problem is when I have a `~` in the field it doesn't match. So here only the first and last match with the following statement :

`SELECT myField FROM myTable WHERE myField LIKE REPLACE('%' + myCriteria + '%', '~', '_');`

Comment: Replace the `~` with a `%`.

Comment: And why do you think I do a `REPLACE('%' + myCriteria + '%', '~', '_')` ? The `_` is a wildcard for one character

Comment: But you said only the first and last match. So I was providing another solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you. If you prefer my problem is when the field in the database contains a `~` any char in the criteria must match with it. but it MUST be only and only one char. Or for `A%C` `AC` will match and it can't. I need to have one char between A and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the patterns and the field are adjusted to the left.
If this is indeed the case, with my head bowed (full of sadness), here is a function.

```
create function is_a_match (@myField varchar(100),@myCriteria varchar(100))
returns bit
as
begin

    declare  @i                 int = 0
            ,@is_a_match        bit = 1
            ,@len_myField       int = len(@myField)
            ,@len_myCriteria    int = len(@myCriteria)
            ,@myField_c         char(1)
            ,@myCriteria_c      char(1)

    While 1=1
    begin

        set @i += 1 

        if @i > @len_myCriteria break

        if @i > @len_myField    
        begin 
            set @is_a_match = 0 
            break 
        end

        set @myField_c    = substring(@myField   ,@i,1)
        set @myCriteria_c = substring(@myCriteria,@i,1)

        if not (@myField_c = '~' or @myCriteria_c = '~' or @myField_c = @myCriteria_c) 
        begin 
            set @is_a_match = 0 
            break 
        end

    end

    return @is_a_match
end

GO
```

---

```
select      myCriteria
           ,dbo.is_a_match (myField,myCriteria) as is_a_match

from        (values ('~63-4-AKS~M'                          )
                   ,('963-4-AKS1M'                          )
                   ,('963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150AAA'            )
                   ,('963-4-AKSAM2RN21AXA150AAA'            )
                   ,('963-4-AKSCM2RN21AXA150A060C1D1DSDXX'  )
                   ,('963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX'  )
                   ,('963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1X1D~~XX'  )
                   ,('963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XXYY')

            ) c (myCriteria)
           ,(values ('963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX'  )
            ) f (myField)
```

---

> ```
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | myCriteria                            | is_a_match |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | ~63-4-AKS~M                           | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKS1M                           | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150AAA             | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKSAM2RN21AXA150AAA             | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKSCM2RN21AXA150A060C1D1DSDXX   | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX   | 1          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1X1D~~XX   | 0          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> | 963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XXYY | 0          |
> +---------------------------------------+------------+
> ```

---

You are mixing between the field and the patterns.
The field may not hold wildcards.

E.g.
This is not a match because of the 'A's

963-4-AKS~M2RN21AXA150~~~0C1D1D~~XX
963-4-AKS**A**M2RN21AXA150**AAA**

Comment: It's not me, it's the client. I tried to explain him, but no result :(

Comment: Yes, in your example if the first is in the database, the second must match. As I said, in the other way no problem, but like this it's pretty hard.

Comment: @Shadam since each char on either side of the comparison can be a pattern OR a test value for the pattern, seems like a custom function like this (or similar char-by-char logic) will be required.  Yes, it will be a performance hit.  Have you tested this answer out?

Comment: @SlimsGhost, actually double performance hit... The only possible JOIN in this scenario is LOOP JOIN...

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Dude you're totally insane but it's actually working ! You're now and forever my SQL hero ^^

Comment: @All use as `select myField from myTable where dbo.is_a_match(myField, myCriteria) = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

If you could tighten the constraints on the wildcard, you might have a fighting chance here.  What I mean is that you generate the valid permutations if a wildcard is presented in the persisted data. Then query the permutations with your existing query.

But if every wildcard has 36 possible options, this becomes exponentially painful.

Comment: It's a `NVARCHAR(100)` field and every single f****** char in it can be a wildcard. My client is insane and does not understand how this can destroy the application performance.

Comment: The string feels like some kind of a model number, meaning that there has to be a master list somewhere that could constrain this.  Am I off base?